# Print all the files inside a dir through batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to write a batch file in DOS which reads all the files from the input directory and display the list of files on the screen using FOR loop.

Answer (score 0):

`dir` for the files in the directory

`dir /s` if you want to include the files in the sub-directories.

[`microsoft command line reference`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true)

edit:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.*) DO echo %%i
```

This will print out the names of all the files in the directory you run the batch file in.

Comment: Thanks, I want to do it with the help of the FOR loop. Can you please suggest.