# batch command that will loop through files ending in “.txt” and display file contents

Tags: batch-file

I'm pretty sure I am just missing something small, but I am trying to figure out how to loop through the contents of a directory, identify those with a `.txt` extension, and display the contents of the `.txt` files to the display.

I searched for an answer to this but couldn't find it specifically. I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256387/print-all-the-files-inside-a-dir-through-batch-file) that shows how to find all the `.txt` and use `echo` to display the file name.

I also found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379242/display-the-contents-of-a-txt-in-a-batch-file) that shows how to use `Type` to display the file contents, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141068/create-a-batch-file-that-reads-all-the-text-files-contained-in-current-directory) that combines them sort of. But I keep getting errors when I try different variations on using `type` in a `for` loop.

I've tried:

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do type %%i
```

and

```
for  %%i in (*.txt) do (
type %%i
echo.
)
```

But both of those are giving errors. I'm sure it's something simple I am missing.

**Update:**

The problem was spaces in the filenames. Adding quotes around the `%%i` following `Type` fixed it.

Comment: Perhaps you should be more explicit about the errors you are encountering. Possibly you are attempting to run direct from the prompt (reduce each `%%` to `%`) or possibly you have spaces in the filenames (enclose the target of the `type` command in "quotes"). Or maybe something else - without seeing your code and a description of the error encountered, we're guessing.

Comment: Awesome, you actually got it correct with the spaces in the filenames. Putting the %%i in quotes fixed it completely. Sorry for not including error messages, I will make sure to do that next time. Thanks Magoo!

Comment: You may also use `type *.txt` for an _equivalent_ result...

Answer (score 0):

No need for any FOR loop. `type *.txt` will do the trick. Each file name will be printed to stderr, followed by the content on stdout. By default, both stderr and stdout appear on the console. There will be one or two line gaps between each file name and file content.

If you don't want to see the file names, then `type *.txt 2>nul`. But then there is no gap between each file.